# Userform1.Show is looking for a different workbook? How do run it in the active WorkBook?

Tags: excel, vba

I can not see how this macro is attached to the old worksheet, it will not run when copied to a new WorkBook with a different name. Since it is being run from within the WorkBook there is no conflict with WorkBook name spelling or location.  The WorkBook name is appended with the date every time I save it.

---

This is the entire macro:

```vb
Sub PricingandUploadCenter()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

---

**Error Message:**

When I click on the macro to run it it says "C:\Inventory\Pricing_2015_09_19.xslm' could not be found.  Check the spelling of the name, and verify that the file location is correct."

**Macro Activation:**

I have Customized the Ribbon (File|Options|Customize Ribbon) and added a New Group.  While in "Customize Ribbon" I selected the "Choose commands from:" dropbown box, I selected "Macros".  I then selected a Macro I had already created in the VBA Editor which is the one line shown above.

When I clicked the newly created button it showed the UserForm1 and ran flawlessly in the original WorkBook.

**Symptoms:**

I copied the Workbook to a new file name.  The VBA code is present and editable in the copied worksheet.

Now when I click the button (which copied over from the old file) I get the error message shown in "Error Message" above.

I can not see how this macro is attached to the old worksheet.

I have included the UserForm1 code below.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks, CraigM

**UserForm1 Code:**

With UserForm1
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.95 * Application.Width) - (0.95 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End With

```
With cmbGetData
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbCouponCodes
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbCustomerOrders
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbDiamond
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbCalRegularPrice
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbDiscontinuedItems
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbMasterOfMasters
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbProductTags
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbSalePrice
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cbxSelectColumn
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
    .Height = 20

End With

With cbxSelectWorkSheet
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Height = 20
   '.Font.Bold = True
   '.TextAlign = 2      'Center
End With

With cmbShippingClasses
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbDeleteOldSheets
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmdExit
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmdPrepareBF_UpLoad
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbSalePrice
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbSaveWorkSheet
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbSaveWorkbook
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbSortWorkSheet
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 10
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With UserForm1.cmbSortWorkSheets
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbCustomerData
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbStoreExporterCategories
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbStoreExporterProducts
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbProductTags
    .Font.size = 11
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With

With cmbWebsiteUsers
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.size = 11
   '.Font.Bold = True
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make customizations to the Excel ribbon, the system saves the changes into a configuration file. To see the contents of the Configuration file, go to File --> Options --> Customize Ribbon. In the lower left corner, you see an option to Import/Export. Choose to Export, and save the file wherever you'd like. You can then open the file with Notepad or any XML viewer.

As an example, I created a group, then a macro in an unsaved Workbook called `Book1`. I then saved the Workbook with a new name and the macro didn't work.
My customization file initially:

```
<mso:cmd app="Excel" dt="1" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon><mso:qat/>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab idQ="mso:TabHome">
                <mso:group id="mso_c2.F674B62" label="New Group" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:button idQ="x1:Book1_Test_0_F6780B4" label="Test" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Book1!Test" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

Notice in the tag `<mso:button...>` there is an `OnAction` property, and notice how it starts with `Book1`. This is why the file looks for the macro `Test` located inside of Book1. By simply removing that, saving the Customization file, then reimporting it, the button looks for the `Test` macro in the active workbook.

Keep in mind, when you reimport the Customization file, it will overwrite any previous customizations (although they'd all be in the file that you exported anyway). So, make a copy of the file before you make changes just in case you screw up.